# create react component from string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a list of array, I would want to match the string with component name, is that possible? I tried this https://codesandbox.io/s/lpzq3jvjm7

```
function App() {
  const obj = {
    name: "Name"
  };

  const capitalize = (s) => {
    if (typeof s !== 'string') return ''
    return s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {React.createElement(capitalize(obj.name), {
        name: "james"
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

doesn't seem to work, any clue?

Comment: @CodeManiac what if I alrdy have the component but it's at other file? https://codesandbox.io/s/5k41vv116n

Comment: You can import from that file `import Name from whatever path of that file`

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell what error you were actually running into since you didn't have a component called `Name`. Simple fix?

```
function Name(props) {
  return props.name
}

function App() {
  const obj = {
    name: Name
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {React.createElement(obj.name, {
        name: "james"
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Prints `james` on the page.

**Update**

You are missing a few things.. firstly importing your component

```
import Name from './Name'
```

and inside `Name.js` you were missing the react import

```
import React from 'react'
export default ({ name }) => <h1>my name is {name}</h1>;
```

and make sure to set the actual value of `Name` to your object, not a string `"Name"

```
const obj = {
  name: Name
};
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/k37zxv3rmr)

[image]

Comment: I have the Name component,it is at Name.js